# Limit of $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\ln2}$

Tags: real-analysis

I need prove that $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\ln2} \rightarrow 0$. I think that it can be possible if I use squeeze theorem, but I have: $\frac{1}{n}<\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\ln2}<...$ and I don't have idea what can be a "...". Any ideas?

Comment: maybe $\frac{1}{n}^{1/2}$?

Comment: $n^{\ln 2}\to \infty$, is this not clear?

Comment: Why not simply use the continuity of  power functions?

Comment: @Bernard, because it is task with a series and I can not functions in it. It is only part of my task, but it was my only problem so I did not write the whole task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Squeeze theorem is applicable. Note that $$e<4\iff \sqrt e<2$$therefore $$\left({1\over n}\right)^{\ln\sqrt e}=\sqrt{1\over n}>\left({1\over n}\right)^{\ln 2}>0$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$\log 2\ge\frac12\implies n^{\log 2}\ge n^{1/2}\implies\frac1{n^{\log 2}}\le\frac1{n^{1/2}}$$